# Azure Storage queries fail with "the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We're seeing dramatic decrease in performance of our services and getting the error when we try to connect to our Azure Storage:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "StorageException",
    "message": "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the
     system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full."
  },
  "success": false
}
```

How do we solve it?

Comment: What kind of storage are we talking about?  Blob storage, queue, table storage?  Just doing a quick Google on your error text above did bring up [this](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1127) Github issue about exceeding the maximum number of ports.

Comment: @DavidYates Mostly tables.